# Get list of users who accessed SQL Server during specific time

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I need to get the list of User LanIds who accessed SQL Server (2012) during the specific time range. How can I get this information? Thank you in advance for any pointers.

Comment: Unless you are [tracking successful logins](http://i.stack.imgur.com/HgCyU.png) (not the default behavior), SQL Server doesn't maintain a history of users for you. To do this you'd have to set up your own server-side trace, extended events or auditing.

Comment: Thanks for this information Aaron, unfortunately the default behavior was selected. So, my question is if the tracking successful logins were set, how would I be able to get the list of users? Will they be stored in some system database?

Comment: Successful logins would be in the SQL Server log.